# Install non-gem library in Ruby

Tags: ruby, graph-theory, rgl

How do you install a library that is not a gem in Ruby?

I'm trying to use [graphy](https://github.com/bruce/graphy).

In the example usage, it says to `require 'graphy'`, but even when my ruby file is in the same directory as `graphy.rb`, I get the following error:

```
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- graphy.rb (LoadError)
from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
from foo.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: oh sheeeeet. this is a good find. off to go figure out how to make it work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell ruby to look in the current dir using the `-I` flag:

```
ruby -I. my_script.rb
```

To see the ruby load path, add `puts $:` at the top of your script.

Answer (score 1):

Everything works fine. I have pasted my IRB try below.

```
Yasky$ cd Projects/ruby/bruce-graphy-70f213b/lib/
lib Yasky$ irb
ruby-1.8.7-p352 :001 > require 'graphy'
 => true 
ruby-1.8.7-p352 :002 > dg = Graphy::Digraph[1,2, 2,3, 2,4, 4,5, 6,4, 1,6]
 => Graphy::DirectedGraph[Graphy::Arc[2,3,nil], Graphy::Arc[1,6,nil], Graphy::Arc[2,4,nil], Graphy::Arc[4,5,nil], Graphy::Arc[1,2,nil], Graphy::Arc[6,4,nil]] 
ruby-1.8.7-p352 :003 > exit
lib Yasky$
```

Explicitly specifying your current directory in your load path may do the trick.

**EDIT:** Oops, I was too late (:

Comment: Thanks! It seems it doesn't work with Ruby 1.9.2, but 1.8.7 does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, the author is using Jeweler to manage his gemspec. I'm not that familiar with Jeweler, but AFAIR, you generate and install a Gem with `rake install`. You may need to generate a version number first with `rake version:write MAJOR=0 MINOR=0 PATCH=1`.

Comment: If I recall correctly there's AFAIK and IIRC but not AFAIR as far as I know.